# How to continuously read a File in Java?

Tags: java

There is a file that contains 5 sets of 8 numbers. Each set are the "scores" for contestants (5 contestants total). My task is to read the file to get each set, cut out the highest and lowest scores, and then calculate the average score for each contestant.
The task also requires us to use a method to calculate averages, so I am not allowed to jam my whole program into the main method.

Here is the data set for reference:

```
8.4 9.1 8.5 8.4 9.1 8.7 8.8 9.1
7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0
8.0 7.9 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 8.1
7.0 9.1 8.5 8.4 7.0 8.7 8.8 9.1
7.0 7.9 7.0 7.8 7.0 5.0 7.0 7.5
```

However, I have ran into a problem. The averages for each contestant calculate to be the same. This is because every time I call the average() method, it creates a new instance of the file reading, so it reads the 1st 8 digits every single time.

Here is my code:

```
//Code

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DhruvPTheWinner{

 //Method for averaging
 public static double average()
 {
     double avg = 0.0;
     double sum = 0.0;
     double val = 0.0;
     double highest = -999.0;
     double lowest = 999.0;

     //This is how we were taught to read a file, using Try and Catch to "import" the file
     Scanner inFile = null;
     try{
            inFile = new Scanner (new File("theWinner.dat"));
        }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

     for(int j = 1; j <= 8; j++){
         val = inFile.nextDouble();
         //If statement to contain highest
         if(val > highest)
         {
             highest = val;
         }
         //If statement to contain lowest
         if(val < lowest)
         {
             lowest = val;
         }

         //Add the value (one of 8 #s) to the sum
         sum += val;

        }

     //Take out highest and lowest so avg only includes middle 6
     sum = (sum-highest)-lowest;
     avg = sum/6;

     return avg;
    }

 public static void main(String[] args){
        //Scores for the Contestants
        double c1Score = average();
        double c2Score = average();
        double c3Score = average();
        double c4Score = average();
        double c5Score = average();
        //Printing the scores
        System.out.printf("c1 is %.3f \nc2 is %.3f \nc3 is %.3f \nc4 is %.3f \nc5 is %.3f", c1Score, c2Score, c3Score, c4Score, c5Score);

 }
}
```

When ran, this is the output:

```
c1 is 8.767 
c2 is 8.767 
c3 is 8.767 
c4 is 8.767 
c5 is 8.767
```

How do I fix this problem and make the computer continue reading the file, rather than starting over?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively,you could declare the `Scanner inFile` as a static global variable and initialize it only once in `main()` before calling the `average()` function.

This goes in the class scope:

```
public class DhruvPTheWinner{
    private static Scanner inFile=null;
```

Put this in main:

```
     try{
            inFile = new Scanner (new File("theWinner.dat"));
        }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

The rest remains same.

Comment: This makes sense. Now, the File object belongs to the whole class rather than just our main class or just the method. It worked as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that every time you are calling `average` you are re-opening the file (at the beginning).

Try splitting into two parts

1) In `main` function: Open and close the `Scanner` object and Read one row of data into an array

2) Pass the array to `average`

Pseudo-code would be

`Main`

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
     val[j] = inFile.nextDouble();
}

average (val);
```

`public static double average(double [] arr)`

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    val = arr[j];
    .... // as before
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are conveying. The only problem is that we have not technically learned arrays in class yet, so we are not allowed to use them in the program. The issue has been solved though by Pal. Thank you for showing me how this could be done with arrays though!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **Scary Wombat**, you have to declare `Scanner` outside of `average()` method

I think you could look at this problem from OOP side. What exactly do you have? You have **a Context** and it contains a few numbers. Additionnaly **the context** has precalculated properties base on it's data. This **context** should read from the file.

Let's define a context and incapsulate all relative calculation into it.

```
public class Contest {

    private static int nextId = 1;

    public final String id;
    private final double[] data;  // optionally, you can avoid storing whole array
    public final double avg;
    public final double sum;
    public final double highest;
    public final double lowest;

    public Contest(String... data) {
        id = "c" + nextId++;
        // you can calculate all this using one loop (instead of Streams)
        this.data = Arrays.stream(data).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
        sum = Arrays.stream(this.data).sum();
        avg = Arrays.stream(this.data).average().orElse(Double.NaN);
        highest = Arrays.stream(this.data).max().orElse(Double.NaN);
        lowest = Arrays.stream(this.data).min().orElse(Double.NaN);
    }

}
```

Then you need a emthod, that accepts path to the required file and returns list of existed contests:

```
public static List<Contest> readContests(Path path) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(path)
                .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
                .map(Contest::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As you can see, this is complete desicion based on OOP. Then you can use it and pring what you need: avg, sum...:

```
List<Contest> contests = readContests(Paths.get("theWinner.dat"));
contests.forEach(contest -> System.out.format(Locale.US, "%s is %.3f\n", contest.id, contest.avg));
```

**Output:**

```
c1 is 8.763
c2 is 7.000
c3 is 8.000
c4 is 8.356
c5 is 7.025
```